# Regex to find anything after ']' and before '['

Tags: c#, regex, forms

I have a regex working to find anything between the square brackets in a text file, which is this:

```
Regex squareBrackets = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");
```

And I want to create a regex that is basically the opposite way round to select whatever is after what's in the square brackets. So I thought just swap them round?

```
Regex textAfterTitles = new Regex(@"\](.*?)\[");
```

But this does not work and Regex's confuse me - can anyone help?
Cheers

Comment: Try (?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*) instead of (.*?)

Comment: You can use the same regex as `var parts = squareBrackets.Replace(input, "\xffff").Split('\xffff');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lookbehind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion):

```
var textAfterTiles = new Regex(@"(?<=\[(.*?)\]).*");
```

You can combine it with a [lookahead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) if you have multiple such bracketed groups, such as:

```
var textAfterTiles = "before [one] inside [two] after"
```

And you wanted to match `" inside "` and `" after"`, you could do this:

```
new Regex(@"(?<=\[(.*?)\])[^\[]*");
```

Answer (score 1):

The same `\[(.*?)]` regex (I'd just remove the redundant escaping backslash before `]`), or even better regex is [`\[([^]]*)]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b(%5b%5e%5d%5d*)%5d&i=A+bracket+is+a+tall+punctuation+mark%5b1%5d+typically+used+in+matched+pairs+within+text%2c%5b2%5d+to+set+apart+or+interject+other+text.),  can be used to *split* the text and get the text outside `[...]` (if used with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` modifier):

```
var data = "A bracket is a tall punctuation mark[1] typically used in matched pairs within text,[2] to set apart or interject other text.";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", Regex.Split(data,@"\[([^]]*)]",RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)));
```

Output of the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/oPJPr4):

```
A bracket is a tall punctuation mark
 typically used in matched pairs within text,
 to set apart or interject other text.
```

The `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag makes the capturing group inside the pattern non-capturing, and thus, the captured text is not output into the resulting split array.

If you do not have to keep the same regex, just remove the capture group, use `\[[^]]*]` for splitting.

Comment: Hi there sorry for the long reply. This is just returning the titles like the first regex does I'm afraid. I'm using a HRM file for a cycling computer if that helps.

Comment: The regex is the same, **methods** are different. You cannot get the same results if you use `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` modifier. Try to `Regex.Split` without a group: `@"\[[^]]*]"`. See the demo, follow each step as in the demo.

Comment: Did you use the code from my demo or did you modify it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
\]([^\]]*)\[
```